# RegEx within sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm having an issue using a RegEx within sed.  I've proven my RegEx works with the RegEx online tools.  See my example [here](https://regex101.com/r/YpK5ky/2).  The regular expression is trying to identify commas within double quotes.  Sed expression is:

```
echo '"","46:5b:da:81:73:44","Apple, Inc.","BluetoothDetect","Bluetooth Low Energy",-91' | sed -E 's/,\(?!\(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*$\)/ /g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` doesn't support constructs like `(?!...)`, they are part of PCRE or Perl regexes, not the extended regular expression.

You can use Perl which has its own regular expression variant, similar to PCRE:

```
perl -pe 's/,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/ /g'
```

I'm not sure why you need to remove the commas, though. Excel understands double quotes in CSV files and can correctly handle them.

Answer (score 2):

To do it with sed, you can define a label `:a` and add a conditional jump to this label `ta`. `t` jumps to the label `:a` until there's nothing to replace.

```
sed ':a;s/,\([^"]*"\(,"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*$\)/ \1/;ta' file
```

Note that Excel is able to properly import a csv file if you ensure that the field delimiter, the record separator, the protection character and the escape character are properly set.